# How can I configure isc dhcpd to provide option 150 for Cisco phones?

Tags: dhcp, cisco, voip

Cisco phones use the proprietary option 150 to tell the phone what server to contact for configuration information.

How can I provide this option using the ISC DHCP server on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to provide option 150 (or other custom options) two configuration entries are required, first, in the top level of the configuration file located at `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` you need to define your custom option:

```
option voip-tftp-server code 150 = { ip-address };
```

Then, in the subnet stanza for where you need to provide the information you'll configure the option with the appropriate value.

```
subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  [...]
  option voip-tftp-server 10.101.0.10;
}
```

If you place the option definition in the subnet stanza then dhcpd will not work.

Answer (score 2):

It can be:

option tftp-servers code 150 = array of ip-address;

option tftp-servers 10.20.10.1, 10.20.11.1;